# Entity Framework LINQ - DateTimeOffset Conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, datetimeoffset

We have stored data in DB in DateTimeOffset in various offsets.

We want to get all results which have the same date as parameter date with specified offset.

For example, we want to get all results which date is **15.11.2018 in offset +01:00**

Following results should return accordingly:

```
15.11.2018 00:00 +01:00  == YES
14.11.2018 22:00 +05:00  == YES
16.11.2018 01:00 -06:00  == YES
14.11.2018 22:00 +01:00  == NO
16.11.2018 02:00 -01:00  == NO
15.11.2018 00:00 -06:00  == NO
```

When we create LINQ to Db:

**Problematic Approach 1 : .Date**

```
DateTimeOffset parameter = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 15, 11, 0, 0, 0, 
                                 new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

var results = from item in db.data
              where item.DateTimeOffsetValue.Date  == parameter.Date
```

In this scenario, we try to use .Date property which returns the date property of the value. However we this solution cant be applied because:

- Entity Framework doesn't support .Date
- Even if supported, the DateTimeOffset wont be converted and the returned data would be same dates but in various offsets - wrong results. We want same dates in given offset

**Problematic Approach 2 : Truncate Time**

Similar bad results will be with TruncateTime which cuts the time part (so EF LINQ wont crash), however, it doesnt convert DateTimeOffsets to same offset zone so the results would be same dates but in various offsets - wrong results. We want same dates in given offset

**Problematic Approach 3 : Entity Framework Limitations**

We searched for many hours but it looks like Entity Framework doesnt support conversion of DateTimeOffset to specified offset or even UTC (im very surprised by lack of such important functionality)

**Conclusion**

So far we are unable to perform this operation. Please give us a hint.

Comment: Can you use `DbFunctions.DiffHours` and see if the difference is +/- 12 hours from noon on the date in question or less than 24 hours over midnight?